# Application title is not showing in menu

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-icons

Only the application icon is displayed. I am providing my manifest code and also I have kept my main launcher activity and project name the same, SHPOONKLE.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.avigma.shpoonkle"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SHPOONKLEActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<activity android:name=".Test" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>

                  <action          android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />       
                 <category          android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />        
                <category          android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />        
                <data          
                android:scheme="x-marakana-oauth-twitter"          
                android:host="callback" />     
                 </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<activity android:name=".ShpoonkleActivity1" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>
<activity android:name=".ShareOnFacebook" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
<activity android:name=".Twett" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity> 
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What menu are you referring to?

Comment: main emulator menu ... where all installed apps are shown..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check `@string/app_name` for your application. I suppose it is having blank value.